# Ruby: Create a filter for methods

Tags: ruby, methods, filter

I have multiple methods which are very repetitive:

```
def method1 specific, options = {}
    scopes = options[:scope] || [:favorites]
    if scopes.size > 1
        # do a
    else
        # do b
    end
end

def method2 options = {}
    scopes = options[:scope] || [:favorites]
    if scopes.size > 1
        # do c
    else
        # do d
    end
end

def method3 options = {}
    scopes = options[:scope] || [:favorites]
    if scopes.size > 1
        # do e
    else
        # do f
    end
end
```

Is there a way to just use something similar to a filter to vaildate the option `scope` and do a or b in the method that was called originally?

---

Here is how I am doing it right now, although it is not very simplistic:

```
def method1 specific, options = {}
    options[:parameter] = specific
    if options.has_key?(:multiple_scopes) == false
        results = validate_scopes __method__, options
    elsif options.has_key?(:multiple_scopes) && options[:multiple_scopes] == true
        results = {}
        options[:scope].each do |scope|
            results[scope] = # do a (scope, specific accessible)
        end
    else
        results = # do a (options[:scope], specific accessible)
    end
    results
end

# method2

# method3

private

def validate_scopes method, options = {}
    options[:scope] = [:favorites] unless options.has_key? :scope
    if options[:scope].size > 1
        options[:multiple_scopes] = true
    else
        options[:multiple_scopes] = false
        options[:scope] = options[:scope][0]
    end
    if options.has_key? :parameter
        parameter = options[:parameter]
        options.delete :parameter
        send(method, parameter, options)
    else
        send(method, options)
    end
end
```

Comment: `do a` and `do b` are not the same for different methods?

Comment: @IgorDrozdov  They are not the same.

Comment: @IgorDrozdov Take a look at my example, perhaps that clarifies my question a bit.

Comment: what is the difference between method 2 and 3?

Comment: @max pleaner their contents (a/b) are different. It just shows that I have dozens of methods following the same structure, some with specific parameters, the rest just with custom options. a/b are different for each of them. :)

Comment: @jonhue what are your methods doing? What is `options[:scope]` and why do you have to process a scopes array with 1 element different? Maybe there's a way to unify this so you don't need the conditional in the first place.

Comment: @Stefan `options[:scope]` is an array of strings. In my methods I do a/b in dependence of that option. I need to differentiate between these two states because if options[:scope] contains only one string, the results should be returned as they are. If it contains multiple strings, the results should be returned in a hash with the scope as key. So action a/b per method are only different in there way of returning a result.

Comment: @Stefan I updated my code example to explain this further.